# AD620 instrumentation amplifier for shunt resistor

Tags: adc, current-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier, shunt

I would like to measure the voltage drop over a shunt resistor (60mV@60A) and I want to send this voltage signal to ADC with a resolution of 16bit. I want to amplify the signal to obtain better accuracy.
I'm going to use the in amp [AD620](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf).
How do you think I have to connect the shunt with my in amp?

Comment: An AD620 is an instrumentation amplifier, not an option amp

Comment: Looks like 1% (7 bits) is worst-case accuracy. Out of the box, best case, expect 10 bits, what with gain accuracy and offset voltage. Noise Voltage, with bandwidth < 10Hz, is 1uV referred to input, or 80uV in a system of Avcl = 80X used to amplify that 60milliVolt to be 4.8 volts into the ADC. 4.8v/80uV is 6,000 or 12 bits noise.

Comment: Have you checked the allowed common mode range of your in-amp? Probably not...

Comment: @peufeu please can you exaplain why it is important?

Comment: @ScottSeidman do you think it is not good for this application?

Comment: If your instrumentation amplifier only has +-5 volt rails, it will not amplify signals outside that +-5volt range. Why? because the input transistors are not operating in acceptable/linear conditions. Some opamps can tolerate +-0.5 volt above or below their rails. Have you examined the specs on this instrumentation amplifier? Look at the typical circuits-of-use in back of the datasheet.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the supply voltage is +/- 18V

Comment: OK, so you have not checked common mode. According to datasheet, input is not rail to rail, rather in the usual range, 1.5-2V from the supplies. Check if this is OK.

Comment: Should be fine for your application, so long as you use it as directed.

Comment: How I have to connect the AD620 with adc?? @ScottSeidman